# ios ionic webview cannot load images from redirected url

Tags: ios, angular, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, ios-web-app

I have an ionic 4 app deployed to IOS.
It is using images from facebook in the format

`http://graph.facebook.com/1015/picture`

these images get translated to a CDN url like

```
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c196.66.412.412/s50x50/155657_780082286681_4945783_n.jpg?oh=d0d22f7fd9ed5e60410dd7d05ae161b0&oe=5B0D1AA8
```

The app is able to display the user image in browser and android devices fine.

However when testing on IOS device, the image is not loaded. IOS is displaying other images fine and if I change the url to the CDN url, it works too.

However, is there a method to do this dynamically by letting ios know that it can use the redirected image.

Alternatively im looking forward to a suggestion if I can first find the redirect url in angular and then put that cdn url value in the src. Just can't seem to find a good way of doing this translation.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/1015/picture?redirect=false, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture

Comment: thanks @CBroe for the quick response, just what I needed. By adding a simple api lookup in my url builder function , im able to display the image fine.